# Force SSL redirect for a specific path in IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I am trying to configure a redirect for a specific path on our site. I don't want the whole site to be SSL.

For example I want any page at this path:
http://www.mysite.com/sc/ 
to redirect to
https://www.mysite.com/sc/

I tried the following web.config but it does not seem to work.

```
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Force HTTPS public html" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/html/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are matching against the wrong URL. And the redirect is not correct. The following should work:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS for /sc folder" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^sc/" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```